# Is there a better solution than ActiveRecord for batch data imports?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, orm

I've developed a web interface for a legacy (vendor) database using Ruby on Rails. The database schema is a complete mess, > 450 tables, and customer data spread over more than 20, involving complex joins, etc.

I've got a good solution for this for the web app, it works very well. But we also do nightly imports from external data sources (currently a view to a SQL Server DB and a SOAP feed) and they run SLOW. About 1.5-2.5 hours for the XML data import and about 4 hours for the DB import.

This is after doing some basic optimizations, which include manually starting the MRI garbage collector. And that right there suggests to me I'm Doing It Wrong. I've considered moving the nightly update/insert tasks out of the main Rails app and trying to use either JRuby or Rubinius to take advantage of the better concurrency and garbage collection.

My question is this: I know ActiveRecord isn't really designed for this type of task. But out of the O/RM options for Ruby (my preferred language), it seems to have the best Oracle support.

What would you do? Stick with AR and use a different interpreter? Would that really help? What about DataMapper or Sequel? Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm open to using Scala or Clojure if there's a better alternative (not limited to, but these are the other languages I'm playing with right now)... but what I don't want is something like DBI where I'm writing straight SQL, if for no other reason than that vendor updates occasionally change the DB schema, and I'd rather change a couple of classes than hundreds of UPDATE or INSERT statements.

Hopefully this question isn't 'too vague,' but I could really use some advice about this issue.

FWIW, Ruby is 1.9.2, Rails is 3.0.7, platform is OS X Server Snow Leopard (or optionally Debian 6.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, ORMs are a great tool to use on the front end, where you're mostly just reading the data or updating a single row at a time. On the back end where you're ingesting lost of data at a time, they can cause problems because of the way they tend to interact with the database.

As an example, assume you have a Person object that has a list of Friends that is long (lets say 100 for now). You create the Person object and assign 100 Friends to it, and then save it to the database. It's common for the naive use of an ORM to do 101 writes to the database (one for each Friend, one for the Person). If you were to do this in pure SQL at a lower level, you'd do 2 writes, one for Person and then one for all the Friends at once (an insert with 100 actual rows). The difference between the two actions is significant.

There are a couple ways I've seen to work around the problem.

- Use a lower level database API that lets you write your "insert 100 friends in a single call" type command
- Use an ORM that lets you write lower level SQL in order to do the Friends insert as a single SQL command (not all of them allow this and I don't know if Rails does)
- Use an ORM that lets you batch writes into a single database call. It's still 101 writes to the database, but it allows the ORM to batch them into a single network call to the database and say "do these 101 things". I'm not sure what ORMs allow for this.
- There's probably other ways

The main point being that using the ORM to ingest any real sized amount of data can run into efficiency problems. Understanding what the ORM is doing underneath the hood (asking it to log all db calls is a good way to understand what it's doing) is the best first step. Once you know what it's doing, you can look for ways to tell it "*what I'm doing doesn't fit well into the normal pattern, lets change how you're using it*"... and, should it not have a way that works, you can look at using a lower level API to allow for it.

I'll point out one other thing you can look at with a **STRONG** caveat that it should be one of the last things you consider. When inserting rows into the database in bulk, you can create a raw text file with all the data (format depends on the db, but the concept is similar to a CSV file) and give the file to the database to import in bulk. It's a bad way to go in almost every case, but I wanted to include it because it does exist as an option.

**Edit**: *As a side note, the comment about more efficiently parsing the XML is a good thing to look at too. Using SAX vs DOM, or a different XML library, can be a huge win in time to completion. In some cases, it can be an even bigger win than more efficient database interaction. For example, you may be parsing a LOT of XML with lots of small pieces of data, and then only use small parts of it. In a case like that, the parsing could take a long time via DOM while SAX could ignore the parts you don't need... or it could be using a lot of memory creating DOM objects and slow down the whole thing due to garbage collection, etc. At the very least, it's worth looking at.*

Comment: The XML parsing is actually very fast. When I benchmarked various pieces, the XML parsing took virtually no time at all. What's killing me is the expensive object instantiation and poor garbage collection running AR on MRI. Which is why I was considering JRuby or Rubinius. I'm not averse to targeting a different interpreter, but I would like to do this as efficiently as possible.

Comment: @Jason: Can you cut AR out of the picture entirely and go straight to SQL? I think that is what is being suggested here.

Comment: I'm considering it. I'd like to use a more efficient O/RM, or something other than pure SQL/DBI etc., because of the vendor-imposed schema changes. I was hoping DataMapper or Sequel might offer something more efficient. But so far it's looking like some complex DBI stuff is going to be the most efficient. Sucks to be me.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**  *ok just realized that this solution will not work for oracle, sorry ---*

You should really check out ActiveRecord-Import, it is easy to use and handles bulk imports with minimal amounts of sql statements.  I saw a speed up from 5 hours to 2 minutes.  And it will still run validations on the data.

from the github page:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
    books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import

Comment: Thanks for this... even if it doesn't currently work for Oracle, it won't be the first time I've had to adapt or monkey-patch something... I'll definitely look into it!

Comment: This gem however, from the documentation I could find, doesn't seem to handle object relations and foreign key IDs that might already be consumed. Anyone know what would?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is indeed "a bit vague", I can only recommend you optimizing the XML import by using XML Pull parsing.

Take a look at this:
https://gist.github.com/827475

I needed to import MySQL XML, and to be fair, using the XML Pull method improved the parse part in factor of around 7 (yes, almost 7 times faster than reading the entire thing in the memory).

Another thing: you are saying "the DB import takes 4 hours". What file formats are these DB exports you are importing?

Comment: The XML is being parsed by a SAX parser. It's about as fast as it's going to get using ActiveRecord on MRI. The DB import is using ActiveRecord to pull data from a view in a SQL Server DB, and translate that to the proper tables/fields in our DB using a mapping file (currently JSON).

The DB import averages around 105k records per run... the XML import is fewer, but I just feel like this could be much faster.

Comment: It's why I suggested this mini-DSL (the XML Pull approach). It's a bit tedious at first, but I can share a small code of mine -- how I used it to process MySQL XML export files with exceptional speed. Beyond that -- I am not sure the DB Views are the best approach, but I understand you need real-time synchronization, so just exporting and importing at certain periods doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that... I'll definitely play with that gist. The XML parsing is pretty decent as is using Nokogiri::XML::Reader, it's the AR portion that's slowing it down... and it's the DB -> DB portion that's really annoyingly slow... which is only going to get worse as they expand the import criteria.